# Populate model instance with another model data during instance creation

Tags: django

I have creating an app as my learning project in Django.
There are 3 model classes:

```
# MOC class

class Moc(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    my other fields...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            CheckList.objects.create(moc=self)

# Pre Implement class

class CheckList(models.Model):
    moc = models.OneToOneField(Moc, related_name='checklist', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            CheckListItem.objects.create(checklist=self)


# Pre Implement Items class

class CheckListItem(models.Model):
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(CheckList, related_name='checklistitems', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    action_item = models.TextField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    actionee_name = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='actionee_ready_pre_implements', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    action_due = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I am creating Moc instance and on post save signal creating my CheckList class instance and consequently my CheckListItem class instances.

However, imaging that my CheckList once created always should have 10 CheckListItem objects as a pre populated list (like an initial data). I could not figure-out if this is something doable (at least how I am trying to achieve it as per my model relationships).

I do not want to hard code thus items in my HTML, I want to control add/delete of thus CheckListItems for related Moc/CheckList instances as relevant.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Use a `FormSet`/`ModelFormSet`.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem, could you please give me an example reference please... Thank you In advance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Willem good day to you! I followed your suggestion and made some progress however I am stuck again. I have posted another question under following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74132340/modelformset-extra-field-pk-is-rendered-as-next-instance-in-django if you could help me please...

Comment: Problem solved! I have to use InlineFormSets instead of ModelFormSets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using InlineFormSets as it is responsible for FK relationships.